# Why do my logic blocks sometimes turn invisible when I run my model?

Tags: anylogic

I have run into an issue a few times while using AnyLogic where a block in my logic turns invisible when I run the model, but it's visible in the developer panel. Any ideas why this happens? Too crowded around the block maybe?

Here is a photo of the block disappearing in the model run window:
[image: invisible block at runtime]

And the same block in the developer panel:
[image: visible in developer panel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure the visible toggle is switched on in the block property settings

[image]